# Calling Oracle Procedure using hibernate- ResultSet Return only first row data remaing rows data missing

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, hibernate-mapping

While I am calling stored procedure from the hibernate. Result Set returns only one row but in database table having four rows of data.

Here I have attached details of table and data which is comes from the db.

**Table Name** : TBL_EMPLOYEES

```
**Procedure :**

create or replace PROCEDURE  "SP_GET_EMPLOYEES" (
    ecur OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN ecur FOR
  SELECT *FROM TBL_EMPLOYEES;
END;
```

[image: PRocedure o/p in sql developer]

**Java Code(Calling Oracle stored procedure in Hibernate)**

```
Session session = HibernateSessionManager.getSessionFactory()
                .openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.doWork(new Work() {
              public void execute(Connection connection) {

                CallableStatement call;
                try {
                    String aProcedureName="SP_GET_EMPLOYEES";
                    String functionCall = "{call " + aProcedureName + "(?)}"; 
                    call = connection.prepareCall( functionCall ); 

                    call.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR );
                    call.execute();

                     ResultSet rs=(ResultSet) call.getObject(1);
                     if(rs.next()){
                        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                     }


                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // propagate this back to enclosing class
              }
            });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

***o/p:
Surya***

Please help me to resolve this issue. or any other ways to oracle stored procedure from hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code here :

OLD :

```
 if(rs.next()){
     System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
 }
```

NEW :

```
 while(rs.next()){
     System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
 }
```

This is because you are not doing loop, you are only checking condition for the first and single time so.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting single record only

use

```
     ResultSet rs =    call.getResultSet();
     while(rs.next())
     {
        sysout(rs.getString(1));
      }
```

And you are actually retrieving only one record.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code.

I did minor changes and it is working fine.

**Procedure script:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  GET_EMPLOYEES_1 (
    ecur OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN ecur FOR
  SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
END;
```

**Hibernate:**

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.doWork(new Work() {
            public void execute(Connection connection) {

                CallableStatement call;
                try {
                    String aProcedureName = "GET_EMPLOYEES_1";
                    String functionCall = "{call " + aProcedureName + "(?)}";
                    call = connection.prepareCall(functionCall);

                    call.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypesHelper.INSTANCE.getOracleCursorTypeSqlType());
                    call.execute();

                    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) call.getObject(1);
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        logger.info("ID:" + rs.getString(1));
                        logger.info("status" + rs.getString(3));
                        logger.info("Location" + rs.getString(4));
                        logger.info("First name" + rs.getString(5));
                        logger.info("Last name" + rs.getString(6));
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // propagate this back to enclosing class
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```